# Google+ SignIn from IOS invalid redirect_uri Missing Authority: MYAPP/oauth2callback

Tags: authentication, google-plus

I am getting Invalid_request invalid parameter value for redirect_uri: Missing authority: MYAPP:/oauth2callback

I believe I followed instructions for adding Sign In button to my iOS App in order to sign in through Google+. 
I have set up my Client ID for Installed applications using
Bundle Name as Bundle ID: XXXXXXXX.com.xxxxx.MYAPP as well as com.xxxxx.MYAPP
I have also tried to use MYAPP as Bundle Id. To be quite honest I am still not sure what it is supposed to be.
I have tried different values for URL Scheme in URL Types section of configuration, still nothing.
Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: I'm having the same error on my end. Works fine for auth using the application, but won't work via Safari based auth and callbacks. Curious why the callback URL is only using 1 backslash, shouldn't it be 2?

Answer (score 0):

Your bundle identifier is in your XCode project's summary page. In the following screenshot I have drawn a box around the identifier:

[image: The summary page for an XCode project]

If your bundle name isn't what is causing the issue, it's most likely the way that you are rendering your button. In that case, try and share your code for how you are triggering sign in.